# No warning with conversion to int from size_t

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, sizeof, size-t

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int xr = 2;
  int ya = 3;
  size_t zu = 4;
  xr = zu;
  xr = (size_t) ya;
  xr = sizeof ya;
  return xr;
}
```

Compiling yields a warning:

```
conversion to ‘int’ from ‘size_t’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   xr = zu;
        ^
```

but only this warning. As `size_t` and `sizeof` both return unsigned data types,
I would expect to see 3 warnings. What is going on here?

Comment: If anything I would expect a warning from `xr = sizeof ya`, but for `xr = (size_t) ya` the compiler might be smart enough to know that `ya` is an `int` and the cast will not cause any troubles.

Comment: `xr = sizeof ya;` may  generate a warning if `sizeof ya > INT_MAX;`

Comment: @CherubimAnand I know, it's the *types* I was thinking about. The `sizeof` expression, in either form, returns a value with the type `size_t`. That should lead to a conversion to `int` from `size_t` by the compiler. This is the same kind of conversion done a couple of lines above, and which *do* generate a warning.

Comment: I run the program and did not got a single warning. My compiler is "TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit"

Comment: GCC, like most C compilers, is very sloppy with warnings for implicit type conversions or conversions from different types. Type safety in C has always been pretty much non-existent. It is up to the C programmer to carefully consider every line of code they write.

Answer (score 0):

cast and sizeof are [C operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), not functions. If you use this example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
size_t mik() {
  return 1;
}
int main() {  
  return mik();
}
```

You get a warning as expected:

```
conversion to ‘int’ from ‘size_t’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   return mik();
   ^
```

being operators, the only warnings you can expect are overflow:

```
char nov[UINT16_MAX];
// large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
uint8_t osc = sizeof nov;
```

or improper use of cast:

```
uint32_t nov = 1;

// conversion to ‘uint32_t’ from ‘int’ may
// change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
uint32_t osc = (int32_t) nov;

// conversion to ‘uint8_t’ from ‘short unsigned int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
uint8_t pap = (uint16_t) nov;
```

now improper use of cast is actually what was done in the question too:

```
xr = (size_t) ya;
```

Here is [the difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions):

> if the target type is signed, the behavior is implementation-defined (which
>   may include raising a signal)

Answer (score -1):

I would say the compiler is smart enough. Consider the below program :

```
  int xr = -2;
  int ya = -3;
  size_t zu = 4;
  xr = zu;
  zu = ya;  
  /* Added test case
   * A negative 'ya' when converted to size_t should change its value.
   */
  printf("zu : %zu , but is this what you expected\n",zu);
  xr = (size_t) ya;
  xr = sizeof ya;
```

Compilation gives :

```
gcc -Wall -Wconversion 38257604.c -o 38257604
38257604.c: In function ‘main’:
38257604.c:11:3: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘size_t’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   xr = zu;
   ^
38257604.c:12:3: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   zu = ya;  
   ^
38257604.c:8:7: warning: variable ‘xr’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int xr = -2;
       ^
```

**Moral**

in C, you're given the responsibility of type-checking. So better take heed of

- Type Size
- Sign of the value, important in the case where both types, in question, have same size.
- Default compiler flags, for example `-Wsign-conversion` is not enabled by default.

when you write statements involving type conversions.